# Add multiple editable text boxes in a PDF file using Python

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, reportlab, adobe-reader

I have a Python script that allows me to add an editable text box in an existing pdf file (with "editable" I mean the characteristic of editing the text content of the box from the pdf editor, like Adobe reader for example).

Python script:

```py
from pypdf import PdfWriter, PdfReader
import io
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter


# With this script I'm able to add an editable text box in an existing pdf file.
# This could be useful to add a text box with a fake word in front of each PII in the pdf file and having the 
# flexibility to manually remove or modify the text content of the boxes directly from the pdf editor (Adobe reader).
# The problem is that I'm not able to add multiple different boxes in the same input pdf file.
# Another problem is that the text box is fixed in the pdf page, this means I can't change the position of the text box
# from the pdf editor.
# I want the possibility to eventually delete some text boxes from the pdf editor.

# Generate the editable text box
def generate_text_box(msg, x_coordinate, y_coordinate):
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    c = canvas.Canvas(buf, pagesize=letter)
    c.drawString(0, 0, "")
    x = c.acroForm
    x.textfield(value = msg, fillColor = colors.transparent, borderColor = colors.transparent, textColor = colors.black, borderWidth = 0.1, borderStyle = 'solid', width = 60, height = 15, x = x_coordinate, y = y_coordinate, tooltip = None, name = None, fontSize = 9)
    c.save()
    buf.seek(0)
    return buf



# This line uses the generate_text_box function to create an editable text box with the message "Hello World!" placed 
# at coordinates (450, 700).
text_box = generate_text_box("Hello World!", 450, 700)


# This line reads the byte stream from the text_box and creates a new PDF using the PdfReader class from the PyPDF2 
# library.
new_pdf = PdfReader(text_box)


# This line reads the existing PDF file named "input.pdf" using the PdfReader class.
existing_pdf = PdfReader(open("input.pdf", "rb"))


# This line creates a PdfWriter object that will be used to write the modified content to the output PDF.
output = PdfWriter()


# This section merges the content of the newly generated text box into the first page of the existing PDF. It then 
# adds this modified page to the output PDF.
page = existing_pdf.pages[0] # Accesses the first page of the existing PDF document stored in the existing_pdf object. The pages attribute of a PdfReader object returns a list of page objects, and [0] retrieves the first page from that list.
page.merge_page(new_pdf.pages[0]) # The merge_page method is used to merge the content of the first page of the new_pdf (which is the generated text box) onto the page from the existing PDF. This means that the content of the generated text box will be added to the content of the existing page.
output.add_page(page) # After merging the content, the page object (now containing both the existing content and the new text box) is added to the output PdfWriter object. This prepares the modified page to be included in the final output PDF.


# These lines open a new file named "output.pdf" in binary write mode, write the modified PDF content using the 
# PdfWriter, and then close the output stream.
output_stream = open("output.pdf", "wb") # This line opens a new file named "output.pdf" in binary write mode ("wb"). The output_stream variable is assigned to the file object returned by the open() function. This file object is used to write the content of the output PDF.
output.write(output_stream) # The write() method of the output PdfWriter object is used to write the modified PDF content to the output_stream. The content that was added to the output object using the add_page() method (which includes the merged text box and existing content) will be written to the file.
output_stream.close() # After writing the PDF content to the file, this line closes the file. It's important to close the file to ensure that all data is properly flushed and that the file resources are released.
```

This is what I see when I open the pdf file with the text box:

[image: pdf file with one text box]

The good thing is that I can edit the text inside the text box using the pdf editor (in this case Adobe reader).

Now, I have few problems that I don't know how to solve:

1. I can't delete the text box from the pdf editor.
2. I can't change the text box position from the pdf editor.
3. I can't add more than one text box to the same input pdf file.